# Android-java audioRecord Unable to write wav

Tags: java, android, save, audio-recording, mobile-development

Audio Recording is upp and actively recording audio signals, then succesfully save it to audio file to external storage of the device, however, when looking for the saved audio file, i cou'd not find the file, yet logcats logs showed the directory of the saved file.

I have been using AFSK to decode audio signals then i wanted to save the audio signals whenever i switch to sstv here is the codes

`
private void startAFSKDecoder(double specialFrequencySSTVactivator) {
checkAndShowAFSKSignalDetected();

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        boolean saveAudio = false; // Flag to indicate when to save audio
        String timestamp = null; // Initialize timestamp outside the loop
        AudioRecord audioRecord = null; // Initialize AudioRecord outside the loop

     //   String outputFile = null;

        Log.d("349 Activation", "AFSK Successfully Activated ");
        if (isDecoderSwitched) {
            Log.d("ALERT351", "Previously Decoded Message is Cleared");
            isAFSKDecodingActive = true;
            isDecoderSwitched = false;
        }


        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
        timestamp = sdf.format(new Date()); // Assign timestamp here

        // Specify the output file path with WAV extension in external storage
       // audioFilePath = externalDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/audio_" + timestamp + ".wav"; // Assign to global variable
        audioFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audio_" + timestamp + ".wav"; // Assign to global variable

        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

        outputFile = audioFilePath;

        try {
            audioRecord.startRecording();
            if (audioRecord.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
                Log.e("AudioRecordState", "AudioRecord is not in RECORDSTATE_RECORDING state after starting.");
                return; // Exit the thread or handle the error appropriately
            }
            Log.d("AudioRecordAFSK381", "Started audio recording successfully.");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("AFSK_Decoder", "Failed to start audio recording: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return; // Exit the thread or handle the error appropriately
        }

        StringBuilder binaryText = new StringBuilder();
        boolean previousBit = false;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (isAFSKDecodingActive) {
            short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];

            // Before starting recording
            Log.d("AudioRecording", "Starting audio recording...");

                // Inside your audio recording loop
            int bytesRead = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            if (bytesRead <= 0) {
                Log.d("AudioRecording", "No audio data read.");
                continue;
            }


            double frequency = calculateInstantaneousFrequency(buffer);
            if (Math.abs(frequency - specialFrequencySSTVactivator) <= frequencyTolerance) {
                Log.d("AFSK_Decoder", "Detected Special Frequency - Switching to SSTV");

                isAFSKDecodingActive = false;
                isSSTVDecodingActive = true;

                if (audioRecord != null) {
                    try {
                        audioRecord.stop();
                        audioRecord.release();

                        // After stopping recording
                        Log.d("AudioRecording", "Recording stopped.");

                        if (audioFilePath != null) {
                            Log.d("RecordedOutputExist", "Records Exist");
                            saveAudioFile(audioFilePath, "audio_" + timestamp + ".wav");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("NoRecordedOutputExist", "NO Records Exist");
                        }

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Log.e("AFSK_Decoder417", "Failed to stop audio recording: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                decoder = null;
                stopRecordingAFSK();
                break;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
                        double amplitude = (double) buffer[i] / Short.MAX_VALUE;
                        if (Math.abs(amplitude) < THRESHOLD) {
                            amplitude = 0;
                        }
                        boolean currentBit = amplitude > 0;
                        if (currentBit != previousBit) {
                            if (currentBit) {
                                binaryText.append("1");
                                //Log.d("AFSK_Decoder", "Detected Rising Edge (Mark Bit).");
                            } else {
                                binaryText.append("0");
                                //Log.d("AFSK_Decoder", "Detected Falling Edge (Space Bit).");
                            }
                        }
                        previousBit = currentBit;
                    }
                    if (binaryText.length() >= MIN_BIT_COUNT && System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > DURATION_THRESHOLD) {
                        String decodedText = getDecodedText(binaryText.toString(), buffer);
                        appendToDecodedText(decodedText);
                        binaryText.setLength(0);
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }

            }
        }


    });
    thread.start();
}`
```

then a saveAudioFile method is called whenever switching from afsk to sstv occured

`
private void saveAudioFile(String sourceFilePath, String destinationFileName) {
// Check if external storage is available for read and write
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
// Get the root external storage directory
File externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

```
        // Use externalDir for saving files directly in the root
        File destinationFile = new File(externalDir, destinationFileName);

        // Get the absolute paths
        String sourceAbsolutePath = sourceFilePath;
        String destinationAbsolutePath = destinationFile.getAbsolutePath();

        // Copy the recorded audio from source to destination
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceAbsolutePath);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

            Log.d("FilePathDebug", "Source File Path: " + sourceFilePath);

            Log.d("FilePathDebug", "Destination File Path: " + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());

            // Delete the source file if needed
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceAbsolutePath);
            if (sourceFile.exists()) {
                sourceFile.delete();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("FileCopyError", "Error copying audio file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ExternalStorageError", "External storage is not available or not writable.");
    }
}
```

`

I have tried to reposition the codes that i have and initialized it outside of the method to be able to make it global, i also tried to put it outside the loop.

i have also tried to make a directory only to save the file init however wav file is missing and unable to be located even if logcat showed that it is saved succesfully

Comment: `// Check if external storage is available for read and write` You dont have to check if external storage exists or is mounted  as it is always available. Further you are not checking if you can read and or write.

Comment: `private void saveAudioFile`. Please put the complete function in that coideblock. It's a mess now.

Comment: `even if logcat showed that it is saved succesfully`Then please tell us what you saw in the logcat to come to that conclusion.

Comment: `Android-java audioRecord Unable to write wav` Is that your problem? Then what type is the source file? Where do you have your problem? At copying that wav file?

Comment: Please tell full path of source file. After that tell full path of destination file.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for the response, i will consolidate the answers to your questions in a mean while.